# Export table to $\LaTeX$ - copy as

Tags: export, output-formatting, formatting, latex

I have the following final expression which is a table (I am posting only a subsection of the table to illustrate the problem). I am pasting it from Mathematica without table formatting (to the bottom of the post) directly and it looks ugly, however, in table form looks as in the picture:

[image: Subsection of table]

Now, I would love to have this in $\LaTeX$. It is a very simple table from the visual point of view, however, Mathematica, upon using copy as $\LaTeX$, gives bunch of errors:

[image: Errors]

Is there a way to get the table in $\LaTeX$ or do I just have to generate the $\LaTeX$ output with Mathematica directly?

```
    {{" ", "C2ung(\!\(\*FormBox[\(1\),
TraditionalForm]\))", "CM1(\!\(\*FormBox[\(2\),
TraditionalForm]\))"}, {"Olivine", 
  "\!\(\*FormBox[TemplateBox[{TagBox[\nInterpretationBox[\"\\\"14.8\\\
\"\", 14.799999999999999`, AutoDelete -> True], NumberForm[#, {3, \
1}]& ],TagBox[\nInterpretationBox[\"\\\"14.8\\\"\", \
14.799999999999999`, AutoDelete -> True], NumberForm[#, {3, \
1}]& ],TagBox[\nInterpretationBox[\"\\\"14.8\\\"\", \
14.799999999999999`, AutoDelete -> True], NumberForm[#, {3, 1}]& ]},\n\
\"Subsuperscript\"],
TraditionalForm]\)", 
  "\!\(\*FormBox[TemplateBox[{TagBox[\n\
InterpretationBox[\"\\\"7.0\\\"\", 7.000000000000001, \
AutoDelete -> True], NumberForm[#, {3, 1}]& ],TagBox[\n\
InterpretationBox[\"\\\"6.3\\\"\", 6.3, AutoDelete -> True], \
NumberForm[#, {3, 1}]& ],TagBox[\nInterpretationBox[\"\\\"7.7\\\"\", \
7.7, AutoDelete -> True], NumberForm[#, {3, 1}]& ]},\n\
\"Subsuperscript\"],
TraditionalForm]\)"}, {"Pyroxene", 
  "\!\(\*FormBox[TemplateBox[{TagBox[\n\
InterpretationBox[\"\\\"1.4\\\"\", 1.4000000000000001`, \
AutoDelete -> True], NumberForm[#, {3, 1}]& ],TagBox[\n\
InterpretationBox[\"\\\"1.4\\\"\", 1.4000000000000001`, \
AutoDelete -> True], NumberForm[#, {3, 1}]& ],TagBox[\n\
InterpretationBox[\"\\\"1.4\\\"\", 1.4000000000000001`, \
AutoDelete -> True], NumberForm[#, {3, 1}]& ]},\n\"Subsuperscript\"],
TraditionalForm]\)", 
  "\!\(\*FormBox[TemplateBox[{TagBox[\n\
InterpretationBox[\"\\\"0.0\\\"\", 0., AutoDelete -> True], \
NumberForm[#, {3, 1}]& ],TagBox[\nInterpretationBox[\"\\\"0.0\\\"\", \
0., AutoDelete -> True], NumberForm[#, {3, 1}]& ],TagBox[\n\
InterpretationBox[\"\\\"0.0\\\"\", 0., AutoDelete -> True], \
NumberForm[#, {3, 1}]& ]},\n\"Subsuperscript\"],
TraditionalForm]\)"}}
```

Comment: Please include your actual Mathematica code in the question, not images of it.

Comment: The code for the table is included at the end of the post. Unfortunately, I do not know how to paste it better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Errors of the sort described by the OP can be reproduced by copying the lengthy block of code in the question to a notebook, prefixing `TeXForm@TableForm`, and executing it.  (Be prepared to abort the execution.)

However, the same table shown near the top of the question can be produced from

```
TableForm@{{"", "C2ung(1)", "CM1(2)"},
           {"Olivine", Subscript[14.8, 14.8]^14.8, Subscript["7.0", 6.3]^7.7},
           {"Pyroxene", Subscript[1.4, 1.4]^1.4, Subscript["0.0", "0.0"]^"0.0"}}
```

(I enclosed numbers with trailing zeroes in quotation marks to prevent Mathematica from deleting those zeros in the display.  In fact, all numbers could be enclosed with quotation marks, if desired.)

Then, prefixing `TeXForm` gives the desired result

```
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
     \text{} & \text{C2ung(1)} & \text{CM1(2)} \\
     \text{Olivine} & 14.8_{14.8}^{14.8} & 7.0_{6.3}^{7.7} \\
     \text{Pyroxene} & 1.4_{1.4}^{1.4} & 0.0_{0.0}^{0.0} \\
    \end{array}
\right)
```

i.e.,

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{} & \text{C2ung(1)} & \text{CM1(2)} \\
 \text{Olivine} & 14.8_{14.8}^{14.8} & 7.0_{6.3}^{7.7} \\
 \text{Pyroxene} & 1.4_{1.4}^{1.4} & 0.0_{0.0}^{0.0} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Incidentally, replacing `Subscript[14.8, 14.8]^14.8` by the more natural choice `Subsuperscript[14.8, 14.8, 14.8]` does not work well, because `TeXForm` cannot translate it to TeX.